# What is the recommend workflow for doing web authentification (HTTP status codes)?

Tags: http, authentication, web-applications, http-status-codes

I'm writing a web application which requires a user login. As you might recognise there are many workflows for responding on invalid user credentials. Most browsers are captable of storing (accepted) user credentails in their credential storage.

My original question splits up into two parts:

1. Which HTTP status code should be send to the user if a site requires a logged in user? I don't mean the situation the user is requesting the login page by herself.
2. Which HTTP status code should be send to the user if he/she has entered invalid credentials?

HTTP 401 is only for the "old style" authentification via browser prompts I guess. I'm using my own login pages to get rid of those browser prompts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many standards for the authentication. Couple of example you can find here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Security5.html
The error code 401 you described is used for the Basic Authentication. It is not old :).

When you use your own login form please follow the standard Form authentication flow:

1. If a user access a protected resource without an authentication redirect to a login page (HTTP code 302)
2. Show the login page (HTTP code 200). Submit a user name to a dedicated URL (generally it is  j_security_check)
3. After a successful authentication redirect back to the original protected resource (HTTP code 302)
4. After a failed authentication show once again to the login page with the error code (HTTP code 200)
5. If a user access a protected resource after the authentication show the resource (HTTP code 200)

To distinguish between an authenticated and not an authenticated session you can use HTTP cookie.
It is recommended to use GUID and not any user information (e.g. user name).

Comment: And HTTP code 403 if the user is authenticated but does have insufficient permission, right?

Comment: I guess you mean 403 in step 3 but you wrote 200 ;)

Comment: You should show 403 only if a user does not have enough permissions. If user authenticated and has enough permissions - 200

Answer (score 0):

401 Unauthorized / 407 Proxy Authentication Required are the only status codes that are relevant.

401 Unauthorized should only be presented if you are denying access to any resource - NOT if you are redirecting or presenting them with a login page.

407 is just like 401 except you are expecting auth to be handled by an external service and you expect to be provided with a Proxy-Authenticate header field.

More typically, you are presenting the user with a 200 OK and a login page.